# Registration form show blank screen after submit

Tags: magento-1.9, register

when customer put information and click on submit button it show blank screen after refresh it looks fine customer registration complete and take to customer account page,
URL show after submit button 
domain.com/customer/account/createpost/

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: No log files not showing any error ,

Answer (score 0):

Go to your customer module and open **AccountController.php**

see a method named **createpostAction**.

and see there should not be **die** method in it.

Comment: Hi , can you tell me exact location of Accountcontroller.php file ?

Comment: app/code/mage/customer/controllers/AccountController.PHP

Comment: Yes file is available their also die method is available i also tried replaced with from fresh setup but not working

Comment: Make sure again there should not be die method in fresh setup too. Check your error log too in your root folder.

Comment: 2016-04-20T16:14:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): 0|1.07047|https://www.shop.com/|FPC_REQUEST_32c49f1db4df4a43dea52c589c917b29|cms/index_index|1000
2016-04-20T16:42:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1|0.13971|https://www.rubamart.pk/|FPC_REQUEST_32c49f1db4df4a43dea52c589c917b29|cms/index_index|1000

Comment: only one file in var/log/ fpc.log